# getting image height and width from zipped files

Tags: php, zip

getNameIndex($i)I am currently using the zip archive function to extract some images, I am looking for a method which gives the filepath of each individual image so I can use getimagesize to get the width and height, below is the method am using to loop through the files.

```
$chapterZip = new ZipArchive();
if ($chapterZip->open($_FILES['chapterUpload']['tmp_name'])) 
{
   for($i = 0; $i < $chapterZip->numFiles; $i++) {
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize(getNameIndex($i));   

    $imageLocation= "INSERT INTO imageLocation (imageLocation,imageWidth,imageHeight,chapterID) VALUES  ('"."Manga/".$_POST['mangaName']."/".$_POST['chapterName']."/".$chapterZip->getNameIndex($i)."',".$width.",".$height.",".$chapterID.")";
    getQuery($imageLocation,$l);
   }
   if($chapterZip->extractTo("Manga/".$_POST['mangaName']."/".$_POST['chapterName']))
    {   
      $errmsg0.="You have successfully uploaded a manga chapter";
      $chapterZip->close();
    }
 }
```

any help with this would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Please pastebin all your code not just one line.

Comment: No way! You have to unzip images first from archive and when they would be available on the server get their widths/heights.

Comment: Yeah ! thanks for that it would have never occured to me otherwise >_<

Answer (score 3):

With PHP's Zip extension's stream wrapper, do not have to manually extract all files:

```
$size = getimagesize('zip:///path/to/file.zip#path/to/image.jpg');
```